# How to pass args to main() in command line in Java?

Tags: java, command-line, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, args

I have a main function and I want to invoke getKey() method and pass 4 params via command line. How to modify code to pass params? Would you provide some suggestion?

command line looks like below:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=logging.properties -classpath ${class_path} --year="2021" --month="2" --day="2" --customerId=1234567
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    List<String> keys = getKey(year, month, day, customerId);
    
    for (String key : keys) {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest rerading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Comment: If there are command line parameters, they are passed in the args[] array.

Comment: Each of the parameters passed to the command line lands as a separate item on the String[] args list. You just need to parse them. Either manually or using some library to do it. If you are going to do this manually you can start by splitting them by "=", and them interpreting  first part as name (e.g. year) and second part as value (e.g. 2021).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to pass args to main() in command line in Java?

First, your command line is incorrect.

```
$ java -Dlog4j.configuration=logging.properties -classpath ${class_path} \
       --year="2021" --month="2" --day="2" --customerId=1234567
```

should be

```
$ java -Dlog4j.configuration=logging.properties -classpath ${class_path} \
       ${class_name} --year="2021" --month="2" --day="2" --customerId=1234567
```

where `${class_name}` is the full name of the class containing your entry point method; e.g. `com.acme.myapp.Main` or something.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/139985 for more details.

Once you have corrected the above, the args will be delivered in the `args` parameter as a value equivalent to:

```
new String[]{"--year=2021", "--month=2", "--day=2", "--customerId=1234567"}
```

Notice that the shell will have removed the original quotes.  (If you want to stop that then they need to be quoted or escaped on command line.  It happens *before* Java even sees the arguments.)

It is now your problem to turn those strings into something that your program can understand.  There are two approaches:

- Implement the argument parsing in custom Java code; e.g. using `String.split`, `Integer.parseInt` and so on.
- Find and use Java command line parser library.  A Google search for `java command line parser` will give you a lot of candidates.

If you want to conform to an existing set of conventions (e.g. https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html), look for a library that handles this.

(Note that the standard Java SE libraries don't include command line argument parsing functionality.  I guess the reason is OS command line argument conventions are sufficiently diverse that a *usable* portable solution is not feasible.)